# How can I stop gtk-update-icon-cache crashing?

Tags: themes

I'm using the [Paper theme](https://github.com/snwh/paper-icon-theme) on Ubuntu 14.04, and every time it updates (or whenever I run the command myself) `gtk-update-icon-cache` crashes with the following error:

```
gtk-update-icon-cache-3.0: **
Gtk:ERROR:/build/gtk+3.0-3sSotQ/gtk+3.0-3.10.8/./gtk/updateiconcache.c:1117:write_bucket: assertion failed: (*offset == ftell (cache))
```

It then leaves a file `.icon-theme.cache` in `/usr/share/icons/Paper/`, and won't run again unless I delete that file or use the `-f` flag.

To be clear, I'm running `sudo gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/Paper`.

Why is it crashing, and how can I make it not do so? Is it a problem that it never seems to complete successfully?